# UITableViewCell - set it to be selected/highlighted... and stay selected/highlighted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like to have a `UITableViewCell` stay lit (blue) after I call

```
cell.selected = YES;
```

Is this possible? Do I have to go another way about it (as in not `cell.selected`)

Comment: That is in fact the default behavior. Under what circumstances are you having difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[self tableView:self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForForRow:row inSection:section]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't specifically returned NO somehow in 
tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath, you should not need to do anything-It is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selection style to stay blue when selected like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
}
```

And make sure your not de-selecting the cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //  This is what you DO NOT want to do
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```